# Stringbuilder parameter

Tags: jsp, stringbuilder

I have this inside my DAO

```
      public String CSNSurvey() {

        StringBuilder mailstr = new StringBuilder("<html><head>");

        mailstr.append("some text");
        mailstr.append("some text");
        mailstr.append("some text");

        return mailstr.toString();
}
```

I can make it to work in myservlet but the question is.. How can I include a parameter inside the stringbuilder...

example mailstr.append("some "+parameter+"text");

please let me know you need more info to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I need more information…

You gave the answer in your question:

```
mailstr.append("some "+parameter+" text");
```

This code is correct to include a dynamic parameter, even if this syntax is better:

```
mailstr.append("some ").append(parameter).append(" text");
```

"parameter" only needs to be a valid java variable. It can be a method parameter, a class field, or a variable declared in the method. Here are two examples:

```
public String CSNSurvey(String parameter) {

    StringBuilder mailstr = new StringBuilder("<html><head>");
    mailstr.append("some ").append(parameter).append(" text");

    return mailstr.toString();
}


public String CSNSurvey() {

    String parameter = getDynamicParameterFromAnotherMethod();

    StringBuilder mailstr = new StringBuilder("<html><head>");
    mailstr.append("some ").append(parameter).append(" text");

    return mailstr.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hello Benoit... thanks.. but can I make it work with a servlet.

Comment: I actually tried it and I didn't get any errors. Now I'm having troubles on how I can make it work in a servelet with parameters

Comment: does this prevents SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

```
mailstr.append("some ");
mailstr.append(parameter);
mailstr.append("text");
```

or:

```
mailstr.append("some ").append(parameter).append("text");
```